# Why is my php form not generating values?

Tags: php, forms

How do you create a form in PHP where the results entered in from the user will be generated in a table? When I test the pages, I only get the start of the table, key and results(values) fields but no values!

Here is my code (I'm shortening the number of fields to two since forms can be very long:

Order form:

```
<?php

foreach ($_POST as $key => $entry)
{
    $totalfields++;
    echo "<tr>\n";  

    echo "<td>" . $key . "</td>";

    if (is_array ($entry)) { 
        $count = count($entry);
        echo "<td>";
        for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
            echo $entry[$i] . "<br />";
        }
        echo "</td>";
    }   else   
    {
        echo "<td>$entry</td>";
    }
    echo "<tr>\n";
}
?>

<form method="post" action="address to the results form page">  


<label for="fname">First Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"/><br/>
<br/>

<label for="lname">Last Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"/><br/>
<br/>

 <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></p>


 </form>
```

Results form page:

```
 <div id="results table">
 <table border='1'>
 <tr>
 <th>
  Field
 </th>
 <th>
  Results
 </th>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP generating the table should be in the resulting page, not in the form page. Or else, you can point the `action` of the form to the same page, to get the results posted and processed on the same page.

**EDIT:** What I mean is this: PHP — as you may know — is processed **server-side**. It means that your browser sends a request to the server, the server processes the PHP file and then it serve the client the processed version.

The problem in your code is that you have the PHP script processing the `$_POST` on the page in which the user is supposed to fill up the form. When a user fills up the form and hit submit, he will get directed to the `action` page, where the `$_POST` will be available and processed. Your misunderstanding is in the fact that you expect the `$_POST` to be available on the page where it's posted, and then to send it automagically to the result page. **This is not what happens because the server doesn't have an opportunity to catch the information you sent on the same page, because it has already been served**…

…unless you make the form action direct to the same page. Then the server catches the information and processes it.

You could go solving this problems in two ways really.

1. Point your `action` to the result page as you are doing now, but move your processing code to the resulting page.
2. Point your `action` to the same page.

You may even want to do something fancy, like check if there is `$_POST` information and, if there isn't, show a form. If there is, show the result. This is not at all difficult to implement as it follows:

```
<?php
if( $_POST ): ?>
<div id="results table">
 <table border='1'>
     <thead>
         <tr>
         <th>
          Field
         </th>
         <th>
          Results
         </th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
         <?php   

        foreach ($_POST as $key => $entry)
        {

            echo "<tr>\n";  

            echo "<td>" . $key . "</td>";

            if (is_array ($entry)) { 
                $count = count($entry);
                echo "<td>";
                for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
                    echo $entry[$i] . "<br />";
                }
                echo "</td>";
            }   else   
            {
                echo "<td>$entry</td>";
            }
            echo "<tr>\n";
        }

    ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
</div>

<?php else: ?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">  


<label for="fname">First Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"/><br/>
<br/>

<label for="lname">Last Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"/><br/>
<br/>

 <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></p>

 </form>

<?php endif; ?>
```

I made a working example for you. Just go to the link and click the <kbd>Run [F9]</kbd> button over the top to see it in action:

<kbd>[**Working example**](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ewv-4bp)</kbd>

Comment: Hello- I'm not understanding you. Are you saying that I should put the table on the order form page instead of the results form page? I did try that early on and after I hit the submit button I got a white page!

Comment: I updated my answer to a better explaination of your problem and misunderstanding. I also provided a working example at the bottom for you to test the page.

Comment: If the answer helped you, it would be nice if you would have accepted it.

Answer (score 0):

This actually posts fine for me (I used `PHP_SELF` for the form action). I would however suggest that you use `$_SERVER[REQUEST_METHOD]` to check for `POST`:

`if( $_SERVER[REQUEST_METHOD] == 'POST' ) { ...`

In addition, be explicit about calling the posted variables (`$_POST[fname]` & `$_POST[lnane]`)

Comment: Do you mean `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`? Please don't rely on unquoted strings (which are actually undeclared constants).

Comment: @IMSoP I don't understand your comment.

Comment: When you write `$_SERVER[REQUEST_METHOD]`, PHP sees `REQUEST_METHOD` as a constant - you could say `define('REQUEST_METHOD', 'Hello');` and it would become equivalent to `$_SERVER['Hello'];`. For backwards compatibility, if you *don't* define the constant, PHP assumes you meant it to be the string `'REQUEST_METHOD'`, but relying on this is a bad idea for the obvious reason that you (or someone else!) might actually define that constant later.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I'll test the pages out again.